# Start JDB with list of breakpoints

Tags: java, debugging, terminal, breakpoints, jdb

Is there a way to start **jdb** and attach from the beginning a list of breakpoints?

Something along the line of `jdb -<?some_flag?> ./breakpoints Main`

It is trully tedious entering these breakpoints manually upon starting a new debugging session, and I am sure there must be a way. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html#options) does not make it clear that such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

I have figured it out with the use of:

- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853628/how-do-i-pass-console-input-to-a-running-java-program-instead-of-to-jdb)
- [this sheet](http://www.science.smith.edu/%7Enhowe/212/Lectures/jdb.pdf)

---

### Solution

The `read` command reads all the commands that `jdb` needs from a specified file. In this file one can write all the breakpoints and commands before starting **jdb**.

---

### Example workflow

So this is the workflow I have now:

1. I have a `.jdbrc` in my Home folder that contains 1 line

```
read break.lines
```

2. Then in the folder where I am opening the debugger I have the file called `break.lines` where I define all my breaks prior to running **JDB**